# What is the geometric meaning of this integral?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

In my math book, there is an exercise where the task is to compute the following integral and to interpret the result geometrically:
$$\int_0^\pi\cos mx \cos nx \ dx$$

where $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, to compute the integral, I separately considered the case $m = n$ and $m \neq n$. For $m \neq n$ we get (using integration by parts and the fact that both $n, m$ are integers)

$$\int_0^\pi\cos mx \cos nx \ dx= \frac{m \cos(n \pi) \sin(m \pi)-n \cos(m \pi) \sin(n \pi)}{m^2-n^2} = 0$$

For, $m = n$, the result is 
$$\int_0^\pi\cos^2 (mx) \ dx= \frac{2 m \pi+ \sin(2 m \pi)}{4 m} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

Now my book asks me to **interpret the result geometrically using terms like "dot product" or "vector space".** I am  curious what the answer is but unfortunately my linear algebra skills are quite basic and I didn't find any geometric relation.

Comment: First of all, recall that $m$ and $n$ are integers: your results can be simplified!

Comment: Thanks! I knew I missed something obvious ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be the vector space of continuous functions on $[0,\pi]$ and for $f,g\in E$, define
$$\varphi(f,g)=\int_0^\pi f(x)g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

Fact: $\varphi$ is a dot product on $E$.

To prove this fact you need to show that:

- $\varphi$ is symmetric, i.e., for all $f,g\in E$, $\varphi(f,g)=\varphi(g,f)$. This is obvious.
- $\varphi$ is positive semi-definite, i.e., for all $f\in E$, $\varphi(f,f)\geq0$. This is obvious too.
- $\varphi$ is positive definite, i.e., if $f\in E$ is such that $\varphi(f,f)=0$, then $f=0$. This is easy to prove (you *must* use continuity of $f$).

So $\varphi$ is a dot product on $E$.

Now, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the function $c_n$ on $[0,\pi]$ by
$$\forall x\in[0,\pi],\ c_n(x)=\cos(nx).$$
Clearly, the functions $c_n$ belong to $E$.

You showed the following:
$$\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N},\ \varphi(c_n,c_m)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if $m\neq n$}\\\pi/2&\text{if $m=n\neq0$}\\\pi&\text{if $m=n=0$.}\end{cases}$$

So your result can be interpreted as:

> The family $(c_n)_n$ is an orthogonal family of vectors of $E$ (with respect to the dot product $\varphi$).

Comment: What a superb answer! Very enlightening! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Define the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\cos(nx)$.

Let's stick with non-negative integers because $f_n(x)=f_{-n}(x)$.

Also define the sequence of vectors with an infinite number of components:

$v_0=(\alpha,0,0,\ldots)$
$v_1=(0,\alpha,0,\ldots)$
$v_2=(0,0,\alpha,\ldots)$ and so on, where $\alpha=\sqrt\frac{π}{2}$.

Once you simplify your expressions (using the fact that $m$ and $n$ are integers) you should find that
$\int_0^π f_m(x)f_n(x)dx=v_m\cdot v_n$ where the dot product here is defined in the obvious way as an extension of the usual dot product in 3 dimensions.

So you can think of functions built from the sum of functions like $f_n$ exactly like vectors and the integrals of their products can be computed using dot products. For example $\int_0^π \cos(2x)(2\cos(2x)+3\cos(4x))dx$ is just like the dot product $(0, 0, \alpha, 0, \ldots)\cdot(0, 0, 2\alpha, 0, 3\alpha, 0, \ldots)$ and so you can immediately compute the result as $2\alpha^2=π$. In fact, abstractly the $f_n$ *are* vectors and the integral of their products *is* a dot product.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a space of functions, say for example $\mathcal(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$. You can define a product by : 
$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(x) dx$$

You can easily verify the properties of inner products. The integral you're studying is the scalar product between $x \to \cos (nx)$ and $x \to \cos (mx)$. In advanced courses of analysis, you learn that this kind of functions (with some constants to normalize them) actually form a Hilbert basis of some functional spaces like $L^{2}$. To be simple, Hilbert basis are the generalization of usual basis to the case of infinite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since $n,m\in N$, then the interpretation of this is to said that the set of vectors are orthogonal, since $\int_0^{\pi}\cos{nx}\cos{mx}dx=0$, ($\sin(n\pi)=0$) .